# Thinking at using Cassandra DB with .net, Dapper.net fluentmigration

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, fluent-migrator

Basically we are looking at solutions to keep our running costs down that will allow us to keep 3+ nodes in sync.

So currently we are looking at PostgreSQL when Cassandra came on our radar.

Can anyone tell me if Dapper.net and fluent-migration works with Cassandra from experience?

Also any advice on this kinda of setup would be appreciated.

Comment: If you look at [link](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Supported-Databases) you will see that fluent migration doesn't support Casandra